# python iterate over variables

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is there a python built-in for iterating over some variables?
Something like:

```py
def iterate_args(*args):
    for arg in args:
        yield arg
```

It would be useful for instance in the following case:

```py
x, y, z = ...
for var in iterate_args(x,y,z):
    do_something(var)
```

Instead of allocating a list, which looks wasteful (is it?):

```py
x, y, z = ...
for var in [x,y,z]:
    do_something(var)
```

Haven't been able to find anything among python [built-ins](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html).

Comment: The function call would allocate a tuple regardless.

Comment: using `for var in (x,y,z)` would be the "built-in".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any such built-in would be much more expensive than creating a tuple, and would in fact *involve* creating a tuple for `args`. Just make a tuple.

In the specific case where `x`, `y`, and `z` are initialized like your example:

```
x, y, z = ...
```

you can just iterate over whatever you unpacked instead of unpacking it.

Comment: yes well let's say i didn't wanna waste space in the exaples by writing those variables in separate lines... i didn't know the *args would be packed into a tuple, in that case there really can't be anything faster that that